# Extract only the column's header from the csv file using NiFi?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I am trying to extract only the headers from the csv file using Nifi. I am new to Nifi and I am not much used to the processors. I am trying to use GetFile->ExtractText->PutFile to get the header line and just output that into a different directory. And this is my regex used inside the ExtractText: ^(.*)\n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ***ReplaceText*** processor to get the header attribute value into flowfile content.

**Configs:**

[image]

```
Replacement Value
${extract_text_attribute_name} //change this to your attribute name
```

**Sample Flow:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand. I was able to figure out.

Comment: @Shu why do we need ReplaceText processor here, could you please explain? I have a similar requirement and I did not understand this.